# Rate of convergence of the maxium of a random sequence

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, law-of-large-numbers, extreme-value-theorem

I came across a problem which requires the rate of convergence of $\sup_{1\le j \le N} |\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_{i,j}/N|$. If sup over a finite number of objects, this is a simple application of LLN. However, what if the number of objects is growing?

Comment: What assumptions do you have on your grid $(X_{ij})_{1\le i,j\le N}$?.

Comment: $X_{i,j}$ is independent across j but weakly dependent across i. Any kind of relaxation of identically distributed assumption can be imposed.